# Bazel get full path of bazel-out/workspace in Skylark

Tags: bazel, checkstyle, starlark, skylark

I want to integrate checkstyle with bazel following this SO thread: [What is the best way to invoke Checkstyle from within Bazel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49074677/what-is-the-best-way-to-invoke-checkstyle-from-within-bazel)
which works perfectly as long as I provide the full harcoded path when building the classpath

**checkstyle.bzl**

```
for file in ctx.files._classpath:
    if add:
        classpath += ":"
    add=True
    classpath += "/home/user/src/repo/" + file.path
for file in ctx.files.deps:
    classpath += ":" + "/home/user/src/repo/" + file.path
```

The downloaded jars are living in the `bazel-out` dir on the same level with my `WORKSPACE`.

```
/home/user/src/repo/
- /bazel-out
- /tools
-- checkstyle.bzl
-- BUILD
- WORKSPACE
```

How can I get the full path of `bazel-out` so I can append it to `file.path`?

Also, it's my 3rd day working with bazel, if there is a better way to do this then please suggest.

Comment: Basically, you either want to use `ctx.bin_dir` or `ctx.genfiles_dir`. The output usually links to former.

Comment: `ctx.bin_dir.path` and `ctx.genfiles_dir.path` return `bazel-out/k8-opt/bin`. I'm looking for the full path to `bazel-out`

Comment: Would something like this help? https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/12351#issuecomment-729743609

Comment: Aren't genrules only writing the output to files? I have something similar where I write the full path I need in a file but then can't read files with bazel, can I?